# Existe um objeto mais leve que o Trectangle e que possa aplicar cor de fundo (background)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Estou utilizando o `firemonkey` (FMX) e fiz uma lista de horários com TRectangle e label, pois usando `ListView` ele não fica muito bonito. 
Acontece que quando existe muitos registros (algo em torno de mais de 20), ele não consegue abrir na hora e da uma travadinha.
 Teria outro elemento **mais leve** para utilizar no lugar do `TRectangle`? 
Algum Layout que pudesse aplicar cor.

Comment: Já tentou usar o Canvas?

Comment: O TRectangle até é dos mais leves. Como está a criar os  TRectangle e label dinamicamente? Talvez seja algo no modo como está a preencher a informação.

Comment: Qual Delphi você está usando?... Se você tiver usando inferior a versão do Berlin e tiver usando o componente do ListBox para percorrer os TRectangle fica lento mesmo, não é o TRectangle que fica lento e sim o componente que você usa para percorrer. Te aconselho a usar o TVertScrollBox.

Comment: Então, eu utilizo o Delphi 10.1 Berlin, e também uso o TVertScrollBox. Não sei se isso interfere no desempenho, mas não utilizo aquele BindVisualy, ao invés disse eu faço a entrada dos dados do SQLite via código mesmo.